# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect in spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

i am using Spring’s WebApplicationInitializer interface to create the application context programmatically and using hibernate with jpa specification for data persistence. i put db.properties file in src folder adding @PropertySource("classpath:db.properties") in WebAppConfig class. i have following jars for hibernate in classpath.............

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4-javadoc.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4-sources.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.6-javadoc.jar
commons-pool-1.6-sources.jar
commons-pool-1.6.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.9.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.17.1-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jta-1.1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar
```

web initialzer class code

```
package com.genesis.init;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    // gets invoked automatically when application starts up
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        // Create ApplicationContext. I'm using the
        // AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext to avoid using beans xml files.
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        // Add the servlet mapping manually and make it initialize automatically
        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

WebAppConfig code

```
package com.genesis.init;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
// specifies this class as configuration
@ComponentScan("com.genesis")
// specifies which package to scan
@EnableWebMvc
// enable spring web mvc to use annotation
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
// plugs in property file which located in the resource folder.
@EnableTransactionManagement
// enables Spring’s annotation-driven transaction management capability.
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

// Tell SpingMVC where to find view scripts
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return resolver;
}

// Enable serving static resources even when DispatcherServlet is mapped to
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

// Enable accessing entityManager from view scripts. Required when using
// lazy loading
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor viewInterceptor = new OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor();
    viewInterceptor.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(viewInterceptor);
}

//Set up dataSource to be used by Hibernate. Also make sure the connection doesn't go down
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("url"));
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("driver"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("pass"));
    dataSource.setValidationQueryTimeout(5);
    return dataSource;
}

//Set up JPA and transactionManager
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    emf.setPackagesToScan("com.genesis.model");

    // let Hibernate know which database we're using.
    // note that this is vendor specific, not JPA
    Map<String, Object> opts = emf.getJpaPropertyMap();
    opts.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);

    return emf;
}

//Let us use PlatformTransactionManager directly to implement programmatic approach to implement transactions
    //To start a new transaction you need to have a instance of TransactionDefinition
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager=new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager();
    }
}
```

database property file is as.

```
 driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
   hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
   user=root
   pass=iems1234
   show_sql=true
   packages.to.scan=com.genesis.model
```

console output is...........

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class com.genesis.init.WebAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:512)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3920)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:293)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1503)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect ]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:73)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: The fact that something is on the classpath doesn't mean it is in your war file for deployment. Are you using maven to manage your dependencies or are you searching the internet by hand?

Comment: no i am not using maven, searching internet by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) as a build tool, so you will have to make sure that all of your needed jar files are in the **WEB-INF/lib** directory of your web application. If it isn't in that directory it isn't on the classpath.

I strongly suggest using one of the earlier mentioned build tools to build your artifact and manage your dependencies. It will save you a lot of searching and headaches.

Links

1. [Maven](http://maven.apache.org)
2. [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org)

Comment: thanks for suggesting but can you tell me what jars i m missing or not included in my project

Comment: The hibernate jars. As I mentioned the fact that they are on your BUILD classpath doesn't mean they are on your RUNTIME classpath!.

Comment: i add the maven dependency <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.2</version>
   </dependency> but it gives EntityManager can't be resolved

Comment: to remove the error EntityManager can't be resolved i put the hibernate-jpa.jar in classpath it resolved but now again getting org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect